# Read inputfield checkbox value from javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am trying to render a component as read-only or editable based on a check-box value. The code I have used is given below.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Relation Iformation" columns="2" id="information">
            <apex:inputField value="{!kpiRelation.KPI_Library__c}">       
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!UpdatePageWithKPI}" oncomplete="RenderPanels()" reRender="pageBlock" />
            </apex:inputField>                
            <apex:inputField label="Edit KPI Treshold?" value="{!kpiRelation.Edit_KPI__c}" rendered="{!kpiRelation.KPI_Library__c != ''}" id="editKpi" onchange="RenderConditions(this)"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

In the above code the Edit KPI threshold is a check box value. I have the below JavaScript to capture the check box value.

```
function RenderConditions(data) {       
        var checkBox = {!kpiRelation.Edit_KPI__c};             
        if(data != '')
            alert('The edit kpi -- '+data.value);
        if (data == 1){
            document.getElementById('{!$Component.pageBlock.condtNum}').style.display ='block';
        }else{
            document.getElementById('{!$Component.pageBlock.condtNum}').style.display ='none';            
        }
}
```

But when I change the value, the value I am selecting is not getting updated in the script. Can anyone tell me what I am  doing wrong here?

Comment: Check individually if document.getElementById('{!$Component.pageBlock.condtNum}')

is giving any value back

Comment: I am not getting the value of document.getElementById('{!$Component.pageBlock.condtNum}'). Moreover i have used the same expressions in different parts of the code and the component is rendered there.

Comment: Is there a component in your visualforce page with the id condtNum?

Comment: What is this variable supposed to be doing?: var checkBox = {!kpiRelation.Edit_KPI__c};

Comment: There is a component by the name.

Comment: @user3197916 can you please post the code showing the element with id condtNum with the pageblock section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
alert('The edit kpi -- '+data.value);
```

you would check like it:

```
alert('The edit kpi -- '+data.checked); // return true or false
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... That helped solve it in a really simple manner.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to use

```
document.getElementById('{!$Component.pageBlock.editKpi}')
```

rather than

```
document.getElementById('{!$Component.pageBlock.condtNum}')
```

to access the input field/.?

Comment: i am trying to render the  document.getElementById('{!$Component.pageBlock.condtNum}'). But the condition to render is got from document.getElementById('{!$Component.pageBlock.editKpi}')

Comment: so you want to say "condtNum" works but not editKpi? In that case add please add complete code where both he components are used